# How can I make my cape visible when using a special set (bought in the Cash Shop)?

Tags: runescape

How can I make my cape visible when using a special set (bought in the Cash Shop)? I bought an special armor with real money, but it doesn't show the cape (that isn't from the set).
How can I make it visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [cosmetic overrides](https://runescape.wiki/w/Cosmetic_override) bought from [Solomon's General Store](https://runescape.wiki/w/Solomon's_General_Store) appear under the **Gear** > **Wardrobe** [tab](https://runescape.wiki/w/Interface#Gear) from the game interface. Unlocked overrides will have yellow text instead of white text.

- Make sure that the pack you've purchased actually includes a cape.
- Check if the cape appears if you disable and enable the outfit override entirely.
- Check if the cape is listed separately in the list of cape overrides.